# Unable to convert this String "è°·æ­Œ��‹¼éŸ³è¾“��…¥æ³•" in readable form in java

Tags: java, android

I am a getting a this String: `è°·æ­Œ��‹¼éŸ³è¾“��…¥æ³•`, but this is actually a Chinese word: `谷歌拼音输入法`.

Can any one help me to know how can I get this correct chinese word?

Comment: Interpret the bytes with the correct encoding when constructing the string.

Comment: which os you are using?is that supports this language.Try by executing on device

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough context here. By the time you've got a `String`, it's probably too late. Give us more information and we're more likely to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese words often encode in `ISO-8859-1`, `GBK` or `GB2312`. As a chinese, I suggest that you try `ISO-8859-1` first, which seems to make more sense.

*update:*

I've just given a shot on `ISO-8859-1`.

```
System.out.println(new String("谷歌拼音输入法".getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

The ouput is:

```
è°·æ­æ¼é³è¾å¥æ³
```

Just so close to your string. Maybe there's a fewer weird characters missing on your pc, so you've got some `�`.

Hope it would help anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Jiang ,but could you please tell me how can these weird characters be changed in some meaningful characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `new String(str.getBytes(),Charset.forName("UTF-16"));`. Create a new `String` instance by passing  the byte array with `UTF-16` as charset type

```
    String str = "è°·æ­Œ��‹¼éŸ³è¾“��…¥æ³";
    String newStr = null;
    newStr = new String(str.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-16"));
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

The above code worked fine.

Output

```
run:
쎨슰슷쎦슭얒뷯뾽맂볃꧅룂돃ꣂ뻢肜뷯뾽
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Adding to that, it didn't work for `UTF-8`. but, it worked for `UTF-16`. So, Chinese characters and symbols are covered in `UTF-16` Charset

Comment: Thanks @Octopus ,But as I told above it is a chines word 谷歌拼音输入法 not 쎨슰슷쎦슭얒뷯뾽맂볃꧅룂돃ꣂ뻢肜뷯뾽

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Firstly, you're using the default encoding. Secondly, you're assuming that the data is still recoverable by the time it's been converted to a string - that's far from a reasonable assumption. Given that an inappropriate encoding has been used, it's entirely likely that information will have been lost.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you please explain me `Why data is not recoverable by the time it's been converted to a string`. I saw your comment in the question as well. But, i couldn't understand it. I need to learn and understand it completely. Can you point me to a reference? `How do I find the correct encoding for the coversion?` Please help

Comment: @Octopus: Suppose you take a bunch of bytes which are the representation of some text in ISO-8859-1, but you read them as if they're UTF-8. Some of the byte sequences may not be valid UTF-8, in which case you'll get replacement characters - you *cannot* retrieve the original binary data in that case. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx for general talk about encodings etc. (It's .NET-based, but that's close enough in this case.) In terms of "finding" the correct encoding - basically you should know it via some other means, usually.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for helping me out. we need to know the encoding of the `String` before we read into bytes. Am i right?

Comment: @Octopus: I suspect you're thinking in the right way, but applying the wrong terminology - you need to know the encoding before you convert the binary data (the bytes) into a `String` to start with. At that point, the OP wouldn't *need* to call `getBytes`, because they'd just have the correct text data already.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, you are right. I understood it clearly now (but used the wrong terminology).Thank you very much. I will learn the page you referred. So, for this question, we cannot do the conversion unless we know the encoding when constructing the `String`

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of Jiang's answer, needing a little knowledge of the system's default encoding, it seems to be UTF-8 interpreted as ISO-8859-x.

Example:

```
String original = "谷歌拼音输入法";
System.out.println("original: " + original);
byte[] bytes = original.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println("iso88591: " + new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Output:

```
original: 谷歌拼音输入法
iso88591: è°·æ­æ¼é³è¾å¥æ³
```

So, use `new String(bytes, "UTF-8"))` to convert the bytes to a `String`.

Comment: Thanks @Laalto , I have used your suggested code. But I found this  è°·æ­æ¼é³è¾å¥æ³ string instead of è°·æ­Œ��‹¼éŸ³è¾“��…¥æ³•.

Comment: Yes, do the conversion on the raw bytes before it becomes a string. To get specific help with that, you'll need to add some specific code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Download Chinese Language from net  .jar and add it in your software where you write the code

it also e done by follwing these steps 
in Eclipse

By default, Eclipse will output Chinese or non-English characters as question marks (?) or some weird characters. This is because the Eclipse’s default console encoding is Cp1252 or ASCII, which is unable to display other non-English words.

To enable Eclipse to display Chinese or other non-English characters correctly, do following :

1. In Eclipse, right click on your application class, and choose Run As –> Run Configurations
2. In Common tab, Encoding group, click on the “Other” and select the UTF-8.
3. Done, Eclipse is able to display the Chinese character now.